# How to hide bottom navigation from fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity witch contain a `FrameLayout` and `BottomNavigationView` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Grizzly"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_nav_bar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/btn_nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way to hide the `BottomNavigationView` from some fragment inside `FrameLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is so easy i made very bad mistake , the solution is :

```
navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

the thing that you must pay attention is you should find view navigationView like this :

```
navigationView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_nav_bar);
```